# Must declare the scalar variable "@varname" in database creation script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, execute, variable-declaration

I'm trying to create a script for basic database and login/user creation for SqlServer
When i run my script I get many errors like:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@varname"

when the variable is used in an `EXEC` statement for the second time during the script execution.

```
declare
     @dbname nvarchar(50) ,
     @userName nvarchar(50) ,
     @password nvarchar(50);
SET @dbname = N'DBNAME';
SET @userName = N'DBUSERNAME';
SET @password= N'PASSWORD';

Begin transaction
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @dbname)
    BEGIN
        exec ('
            DROP login '+ @userName + '
            DROP USER '+  @userName + '
            alter database '+  @dbname + '
            SET OFFLINE 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
            ALTER DATABASE '+  @dbname + '
            SET ONLINE;
            DROP DATABASE '+  @dbname)
    END 

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO
    EXEC ('CREATE DATABASE '+ @dbname)
    GO 
    EXEC (@dbname+ '.[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = ''disable''')
    GO 
    EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100')
    GO 
     ...
    EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET DB_CHAINING OFF')
    GO

    EXEC('create login '+ @userName + 'with password = '+ @password);
    EXEC('use  '+ @dbname+ '
    create user '+ @userName + ' for login '+ @userName);
    EXEC ('EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_owner'', '+  @userName)

commit transaction
```

Have I to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for every query? Is there a shorter solution?

Comment: Remove the `GO` batch separator and try

Comment: You cannot use CREATE DATABASE DDL statements inside of the transaction and you cannot rollback creating of the objects actions.referring the below url:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/594ff024-8af6-40b3-89e0-53edb3ad7245/create-database-statement-not-allowed-within-multistatement-transaction-error-occured?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: @Raj thanks this helps a lot: replacing go with ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950982/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-varname-in-database-creation-script#comment-29693253) and [Vaibhav Parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950982/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-varname-in-database-creation-script#comment-29693778) comments I changed my script and now it works fine.

> The main error was the GO statement that should be removed because it
>   is used to group SQL commands into batches which are sent to the
>   server together. The commands included in the batch, that is, the set
>   of commands since the last GO command or the start of the session,
>   must be logically consistent. You can't define a variable in one batch
>   and then use it in another since the scope of the variable is limited
>   to the batch in which it's defined.
>
> The second error was that I tried to use transaction with statement
>   that don't allow them

I leave the corrected script there as reference:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

declare
     @dbname nvarchar(50) ,
     @userName nvarchar(50) ,
     @password nvarchar(50);
SET @dbname = N'DATABASENAME';
SET @userName = N'DBUSERNAME';
SET @password= N'DBUSERPASSWORD';

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @dbname)
BEGIN
    exec ('
    DROP USER '+  @userName + '
    DROP login '+ @userName + '
    alter database '+  @dbname + '
    SET OFFLINE 
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    ALTER DATABASE '+  @dbname + '
    SET ONLINE;
    DROP DATABASE '+  @dbname)
END 

EXEC ('CREATE DATABASE '+ @dbname);
EXEC (@dbname+ '.[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = ''disable''');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ANSI_PADDING ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET RECOVERY FULL');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ARITHABORT ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL');
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET  ENABLE_BROKER'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET  READ_WRITE'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET  MULTI_USER'); 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET DB_CHAINING OFF');

EXEC ('create login '+  @userName + ' with password = '''+ @password+ ''', default_database = ' + @dbname);
EXEC ('use  '+ @dbname+ ' create user '+ @userName + ' for login '+ @userName);
EXEC ('use  '+ @dbname+ ' EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_owner'', '+  @userName);
```

Answer (score 3):

The GO Statement tells the query analyzer that a batch is complete.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Therefore, the declared variable that are set are out of scope by the time the dynamic code is executed.

If you truly want this in a transaction, then wrap it with **BEGIN TRY/END TRY**  in the **BEGIN CATCH /END CATCH**, perform a **ROLLBACK**.

http://craftydba.com/?p=5930

I never tried this with the CREATE DATABASE statement.  That might be a fun exercise.  Does it undo the database creation?  Something to add to my bucket list to try.

Also, you need to use a **semicolon (;)** when combining multiple commands.  Otherwise, you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code might be it helps:

```
declare @dbname nvarchar(50) ,@userName nvarchar(50) ,@password nvarchar(50);
SET @dbname = N'DBNAME';
SET @userName = N'DBUSERNAME';
SET @password= N'PASSWORD';

Begin transaction
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = @dbname)
BEGIN
    exec ('
        DROP login '+ @userName + '
        DROP USER '+  @userName + '
        alter database '+  @dbname + '
        SET OFFLINE 
        WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
        ALTER DATABASE '+  @dbname + '
        SET ONLINE;
        DROP DATABASE '+  @dbname)
END 
   else
   begin
--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO
--SET ANSI_PADDING ON
--GO
EXEC ('CREATE DATABASE '+ @dbname)
--GO 
EXEC (@dbname+ '.[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = ''disable''')
--GO 
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100')
--GO 

EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbname + ' SET DB_CHAINING OFF')
--GO

EXEC('create login '+ @userName + 'with password = '+ @password);
EXEC('use  '+ @dbname+ '
create user '+ @userName + ' for login '+ @userName);
EXEC ('EXEC sp_addrolemember  ''db_owner'', '+  @userName)
end

commit transaction
```